# Creating restricted temporary Subroutines in ABAP

Tags: select, abap, keyword-search

I would like to offer the possibility to create advanced selects, more profound than the left joins that can be created via quickviewer.

The easiest way would be to allow the user to insert some source code via ["GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL"](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/9f/db999535c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).

But it would be neccesary for me to ensure that this source code doesn't change any data, start other programms or does anything than evaluating data.

My idea would be to restict the inserted source code to some key-worlds like SELECT, LOOP, IF etc. In this case I would need to find all key words in the inserted source code and check it against some white list.

How could I do this? Are there any ways to circumvent my restrictions in order to do some real damage? Are there other ways to reach my goal?

Answer (score 2):

Securing stuff like this is really hard to do, and it's not a personal limitation or an issue with the platform. You can't get the machine to understand what the programmer is doing - see [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Doing a keyword scan for yourself is tedious work. You might want to try  [SCAN ABAP-SOURCE](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapscan.htm) and take a look at the tables the scanner throws out. However, limiting to the most basic language elements will only get you so far, because for any substantial programming, you'll have to allow for external subroutine calls, and then you're vulnerable to about anything. In my opinion, it's better to hand the specifications to a developer and have the report developed with no dynamic stuff whatsoever. This way, you can also ensure that no incorrect reports are created just because the user hacking away at the SELECT statements didn't know about that cancellation flag...